# How can i show the progressbar tkinter while executing another function

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import camelot
import ghostscript
import os
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Tk,Canvas,filedialog
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar

def dataExtraction(file):
    fileName=os.path.basename(file)
    fileName=filename.replace('.pdf',"")
    tables=camelot.read_pdf(file,pages='all')
    finalData=pd.DataFrame()
    for i,j in enumerate(tables):
        data=tabs[i].df
        finalData.append(data)
    finalData.to_excel(filename+'.xlsx')

def tkWindow():
    root=Tk()
    w=root.winfo_screenwidth()
    h=root.winfo_screenheight()
    root.geometry("%d%d" % (w,h))

    my_canvas=Canvas(root,width=w,height=h)
    my_canvas.pack(fill=both,expand=True)
    ####upload button####
    def openPdf():
        global pdffile
        pdffile=filedialog.askopenfilename()
        return pdffile
    upload=Button(root,
    width=20,
    pady=5,
    text='Upload Pdf',
    command=openPdf)
    pdf_win=my_canvas.create_window(10,350,anchor='nw',window=upload)
    ###submit button###
    def run():
        dataExtraction(file)

    runbtn=Button(root,
    width=10,
    pady=5,
    command=threading.Thread(target=run).start)
    run_win=my_canvas.create_window(550,590,anchor='nw',window=runbtn)
    root.mainloop()
```

tkWindow()

I want to add a progressbar when i am calling dataExtraction function inside run and it will show the progress till the dataExtraction executed once done progressbar should automatically disappear. If anyone can suggest me how can i do that that will be great.

Comment: What you have tried so far about progressbar? This example does not have anything about it. Also it's not reproducible. However for progressbar you can check ttk.progressbar widget. https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/ttk-Progressbar.html . Also, to get faster answers you should provide minimal reproducible codes. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @MustafaKÜÇÜKDEMİRCİ please find the below code for progress bar. But i am not sure how can i show the progress inside the run function when i am calling dataExctraction function:pbar = ttk.Progressbar(gui1, orient='horizontal', length=300, mode='indeterminate')
    pbar.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='c')
    pbar.start()